# Aside from Saint Francis of Assisi, were there other famous figures-(distant or near) who walked along the Camino Del Santiago in Northern Spain?

Tags: middle-ages, religion, spain, travel

The Camino Del Santiago/"Road of Saint James" has been a popular destination for peripatetic and religious pilgrims since the 800's AD/CE-(though it declined in popularity during much the Early Modern age). Saint Francis of Assisi was reported to have walked the entire Camino. However, are there any other historical figures-(distant or near) who have also walked all or part of the famed Roadway in Northern Spain?

Answer (score 4):

[Fellow travelers](https://magazine.nd.edu/news/history-of-the-camino-de-santiago/) on the Camino Del Santiago include Italy's Dante and Spanish warrior El Cid. Burgos, the former capital of Castile lies on the road, and some Castilian kings, including possibly Isabella walked on it.

Modern "walkers" would include author James Michener, and I believe, Ernest Hemingway.

Comment: I am not surprised that El Cid walked on the Camino, though I did not know that Dante walked on the Camino.

Comment: @Alex: Among "moderns," author James Michener walked on it, and I believe, Hemingway.

Comment: Like the aforementioned, El Cid, I am not surprised that Ernest Hemingway walked the Camino Del Santiago.  Many thanks for the list of names.